# Why should I use require.js if I still concenate all files on build?

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs, amd

It sure makes a lot of sense to write modular, independent testable code - especially for big projects.

But what difference does using `require.js`/`amd` make in a big project where I still need to concenate & minify my project on build?

Comment: Instead of voting for closing, please make me understand as I do not get this concept at all

Comment: I think there is no need for it. I guess require.js could be used in a development environment, but in production it's _probably_ useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to preface my response with saying that I do think Require.JS is an utterly useless framework.  It over-complicates a fairly simple concept.

That being said, dependency loading is VERY useful when it comes to writing platform independent code.

For example, say you wanted to develop a web application that you can also port into Apache Cordova for mobile apps and into AppJS for desktop apps.  You wouldn't want to rewrite all of your business logic, so it makes sense to build a bootstrap that loads dependencies dynamically to adapt the software to multiple architectures.  That way you only have one product, which is able to run on a variety of platforms.  Add in the usage of NodeJS for server side script and you can not only write front end software, but back end with the exact same code.

Modularity helps a lot with cross-platform projects, but as I said: Require.JS really isn't that useful.  I have found it to be overly complicated.  Instead, I just use an object built around jQuery's getScript function that contains a registry of all loaded packages so that a dev doesn't try to load a package that has already been loaded (larger projects).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of advantages to require.js, such as:

- Conditional loading
- Asynchronous loading
- Logical modules
- Abstraction of nested dependencies
- Multiversion support
- Automated minification

Answer (score 0):

Require.js does recommend using one (or more if that's what fits your project) JS file in production for your JavaScript, so what you're doing is common for smaller projects.  I think there are two main reasons for small projects that you would use it (@Wolfgang Stengel lists all of the benefits).

If you're combining jQuery or other libraries in your JS file, that may not be the right thing to do. If you can use a CDN copy it is likely that the user will already have that file downloaded on their machine, which will take less time to load your JavaScript.

Another benefit is that asynchronous loading.  This will make it so your JavaScript loading will not block the rendering of your web page.  A web page that appears quicker is generally thought to be a quicker site for the end user.